# Is it possible to SSH tunnel on Windows 10 with Git Bash?

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

I'm trying to forward port 5000 from my local machine to a remote server's port 5000

I'm using the command

```
ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@remote
```

However, when I try to make the following curl request on my local machine

```
curl http://172.19.0.2:5000
```

It times out, while the same command does work on the remote machine.

Is there anything that I am missing or is this possible on Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@remote
curl http://172.19.0.2:5000
```

If you want to connect through the SSH tunnel, you have to connect to the local listening port created by `ssh`:

```
curl http://localhost:5000
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, this has nothing to do with Windows but rather my failure at understanding a tunnel works

Answer (score -1):

Try `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5000:localhost:5000 root@remote`

[SSH Tunnel via native Windows bash: Address already in use](https://superuser.com/questions/1119836/ssh-tunnel-via-native-windows-bash-address-already-in-use/1122198)